Deployment of matching rule update fails with an error `Change the matching rule status separately from other changes`
Deployment of matching rule update fails with an error Change the matching rule status separately from other changes.
The previous version which was deployed to the target org is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MatchingRules xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <matchingRules>
        <fullName>AccountMatchingRule</fullName>
        <booleanFilter>1 OR (2 AND 3 AND 4) OR (3 AND 4 AND 5)</booleanFilter>
        <description>This is a custom account matching rule to be used for matching all B2B Direct companies.</description>
        <label>B2B Direct Account matching rule</label>
        <matchingRuleItems>
            <blankValueBehavior>NullNotAllowed</blankValueBehavior>
            <fieldName>DunsNumber__c</fieldName>
            <matchingMethod>Exact</matchingMethod>
        </matchingRuleItems>
        <matchingRuleItems>
            <blankValueBehavior>NullNotAllowed</blankValueBehavior>
            <fieldName>Name</fieldName>
            <matchingMethod>CompanyName</matchingMethod>
        </matchingRuleItems>
        <matchingRuleItems>
            <blankValueBehavior>NullNotAllowed</blankValueBehavior>
            <fieldName>BillingStreet</fieldName>
            <matchingMethod>Street</matchingMethod>
        </matchingRuleItems>
        <matchingRuleItems>
            <blankValueBehavior>NullNotAllowed</blankValueBehavior>
            <fieldName>BillingCity</fieldName>
            <matchingMethod>City</matchingMethod>
        </matchingRuleItems>
        <matchingRuleItems>
            <blankValueBehavior>NullNotAllowed</blankValueBehavior>
            <fieldName>Website</fieldName>
            <matchingMethod>Exact</matchingMethod>
        </matchingRuleItems>
        <ruleStatus>Active</ruleStatus>
    </matchingRules>
</MatchingRules>

the new metadata is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MatchingRules xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <matchingRules>
        <fullName>AccountMatchingRule</fullName>
        <booleanFilter>(1 OR (2 AND 3 AND 4) OR (3 AND 4 AND 5)) AND 6</booleanFilter>
        <description>This is a custom account matching rule to be used for matching all B2B Direct companies.</description>
        <label>B2B Direct Account matching rule</label>
        <matchingRuleItems>
            <blankValueBehavior>NullNotAllowed</blankValueBehavior>
            <fieldName>DunsNumber__c</fieldName>
            <matchingMethod>Exact</matchingMethod>
        </matchingRuleItems>
        <matchingRuleItems>
            <blankValueBehavior>NullNotAllowed</blankValueBehavior>
            <fieldName>Name</fieldName>
            <matchingMethod>CompanyName</matchingMethod>
        </matchingRuleItems>
        <matchingRuleItems>
            <blankValueBehavior>NullNotAllowed</blankValueBehavior>
            <fieldName>BillingStreet</fieldName>
            <matchingMethod>Street</matchingMethod>
        </matchingRuleItems>
        <matchingRuleItems>
            <blankValueBehavior>NullNotAllowed</blankValueBehavior>
            <fieldName>BillingCity</fieldName>
            <matchingMethod>City</matchingMethod>
        </matchingRuleItems>
        <matchingRuleItems>
            <blankValueBehavior>NullNotAllowed</blankValueBehavior>
            <fieldName>Website</fieldName>
            <matchingMethod>Exact</matchingMethod>
        </matchingRuleItems>
        <matchingRuleItems>
            <blankValueBehavior>NullNotAllowed</blankValueBehavior>
            <fieldName>RecordTypeName__c</fieldName>
            <matchingMethod>Exact</matchingMethod>
        </matchingRuleItems>
        <ruleStatus>Active</ruleStatus>
    </matchingRules>
</MatchingRules>

How can we avoid this error?

We were able to resolve this error by Deleting completely the matching rule
sf project delete source -r -m MatchingRule:Account.AccountMatchingRule 

and then deploying it again
sf force:source:deploy -m MatchingRule:Account.AccountMatchingRule 

